# GUI Java actualización de datos

Tags: java, java-swing, interfaz-gráfica, update

Me encuentro desarrollando una GUI en Java y he encontrado un problema con ella y es que al momento de ingresar datos nuevos no se actualiza la información.

Este es el código:

Parte 1:

```
import java.sql.Connection;
import java.sql.DriverManager;
import java.sql.ResultSet;
import java.sql.Statement;
import java.util.ArrayList;

public class DBConnect {
    String PBM;
    String Year;

    DBConnect(String PBM, String Year){
        this.PBM = PBM;
        this.Year = Year;
    }
    public ArrayList <Object> ConnectDB(){
        try{
            Connection c = DriverManager.getConnection("jdbc:sqlite://C:/Users/Trocx/OneDrive/Documents/Proyecto/PBM_DB.db");
            System.out.println("Connection to database has been performed!");

            String sql_ft = "SELECT FACTOR FROM PBM_FACTOR WHERE PBM =" + this.PBM;
            Statement stmt_ft = c.createStatement();
            ResultSet rs_ft = stmt_ft.executeQuery(sql_ft);
            String Factor = rs_ft.getString("FACTOR");

            stmt_ft.close();

            String sql_sal = "SELECT SALARY FROM AN_SAL WHERE YEAR =" + this.Year;
            Statement stmt_sal = c.createStatement();
            ResultSet rs_sal = stmt_sal.executeQuery(sql_sal);
            Double Salary = rs_sal.getDouble("SALARY");

            stmt_sal.close();

            c.close();

            ArrayList <Object> dat = new ArrayList<>(3);
            dat.add(true);
            dat.add(Factor);
            dat.add(Salary);
            return dat;

        }catch (Exception e) {
            System.out.println(e.getClass().getName() + ": " + e.getMessage());
            ArrayList <Object> dat = new ArrayList<>(1);
            dat.add(false);
            return dat;
        }
    }
}
```

Parte 2:

```
import java.awt.*;
import java.awt.event.ActionEvent;
import java.awt.event.ActionListener;
import java.awt.event.FocusEvent;
import java.awt.event.FocusListener;
import java.util.ArrayList;
    
import javax.swing.*;

public class GUI extends JFrame{

    String pbmGot;
    String yearGot;
    public void init(){

        //Paneles

        JPanel Frame1 = new JPanel();
        JPanel Buttons = new JPanel();
        JPanel Principal = new JPanel();

        JLabel jlName = new JLabel("Nombre");
        JLabel jlPbm = new JLabel("PBM");
        JLabel jlYears = new JLabel("Año");

        JTextField jtName = new JTextField();
        JTextField jtPbm = new JTextField();

        TabCalc TableR = new TabCalc();

        JComboBox<String> Years = new JComboBox<>();
        Years.addItem("");
        Years.addItem("2019");
        Years.addItem("2020");
        Years.addItem("2021");
        Years.addItem("2022");
        Years.addItem("2023");
        Years.addItem("2024");

        jtPbm.addFocusListener(new FocusListener(){
            
            @Override
            public void focusGained(FocusEvent e){
            }

            @Override
            public void focusLost(FocusEvent e){
                try {
                    Integer PBMd = Integer.parseInt(jtPbm.getText());
                } catch (NumberFormatException nfe) {
                    JOptionPane.showMessageDialog(Frame1, "¡Ingresa un PBM válido!", "Error!", JOptionPane.ERROR_MESSAGE);
                    jtPbm.setText("");
                }
            }
        });

        JButton buttOK = new JButton("Enviar");

        buttOK.addActionListener(new ActionListener() {

            @Override
            public void actionPerformed(ActionEvent e){
                pbmGot = jtPbm.getText();
                yearGot = Years.getSelectedItem().toString(); 

                if(pbmGot.equals("") || yearGot.equals("")){
                    JOptionPane.showMessageDialog(Principal, "¡Información incompleta!", "Error", JOptionPane.ERROR_MESSAGE);
                }else{
                    if(Integer.parseInt(pbmGot) > 100 || Integer.parseInt(pbmGot) <= 0){
                        JOptionPane.showMessageDialog(Principal, "¡Información errónea!", "Error", JOptionPane.ERROR_MESSAGE);
                    }else{

                    DBConnect sql = new DBConnect(pbmGot,yearGot);
                    ArrayList<Object> s = sql.ConnectDB();
                    boolean  x = (boolean) s.get(0);
                    if(x == true){
                        JOptionPane.showMessageDialog(Principal, "¡La consulta fue exitosa!", "Aviso", JOptionPane.INFORMATION_MESSAGE);
                        TableR.tabFill(pbmGot, yearGot);
                        Principal.add(TableR,BorderLayout.CENTER);
                        Principal.updateUI();
                    }
                }
            }}
        });

        JButton buttDel = new JButton("Borrar");
        buttDel.addActionListener(new ActionListener() {
            
            @Override
            public void actionPerformed(ActionEvent e){
                jtName.setText("");
                jtPbm.setText("");
                Years.setSelectedItem("");
                Principal.remove(TableR);
                Principal.updateUI();
                JOptionPane.showMessageDialog(Principal, "¡Consulta eliminada!", "Aviso", JOptionPane.INFORMATION_MESSAGE);
            }
        });

        Buttons.setLayout(new GridLayout(1,2,2,5));
        Buttons.add(buttOK);
        Buttons.add(buttDel);

        Frame1.setLayout(new GridLayout(4,2,5,2));
        Frame1.add(jlName);
        Frame1.add(jtName);
        Frame1.add(jlPbm);
        Frame1.add(jtPbm);
        Frame1.add(jlYears);
        Frame1.add(Years);

        Principal.setLayout(new BorderLayout());
        Principal.add(Frame1,BorderLayout.NORTH);
        Principal.add(Buttons,BorderLayout.SOUTH);


        add(Principal);

        setTitle("Calculadora de matrícula");
        setSize(400, 300);
        setResizable(false);
        setDefaultCloseOperation(WindowConstants.EXIT_ON_CLOSE);
        setLocationRelativeTo(null);
        setVisible(true);
    }

    public static void main(String[] args) {
        GUI gui1 = new GUI();
        gui1.init();
    }
}
```

Parte 3:

```
import java.util.ArrayList;

import javax.swing.table.DefaultTableModel;

public class MatCalc extends DefaultTableModel{
    String PBM;
    String Year;

    public void creaTable(String PBM, String Year){

        ArrayList <String> Labels = new ArrayList<String>();
        Labels.add("Bienestar");
        Labels.add("Sistematización");
        Labels.add("Póliza o Seguro Estudiantíl");
        Labels.add("Matrícula");
        Labels.add("Total");

        this.addColumn("Concepto");
        this.addColumn("Valor Unitario");

        DBConnect sql = new DBConnect(PBM,Year);
        ArrayList<Object> s = sql.ConnectDB();
        s.remove(0);

        Double factor = Double.parseDouble(s.get(0).toString());
        Double salary = Double.parseDouble(s.get(1).toString());

        long mat = Math.round(factor*0.93*salary);
        long bt = Math.round(0.1*mat);
        long st = Math.round(0.076*salary);
        long pz;
        
        if(Integer.parseInt(Year) >= 2023){
            pz = Math.round(25000.0);
        }else{
            pz = Math.round(24890.0);
        }
        long total = mat + bt + st + pz;

        s.set(0, bt);
        s.set(1, st);
        s.add(2, pz);
        s.add(3, mat);
        s.add(4,total);

        var k = Labels.toArray();
        String[] data = new String[2];

        int i = 0;
        int n = 0;
        for(int j=0;j<10;j++){
            if(i%2 == 0){
                data[i] = k[n].toString();
            }else{
                data[i] = String.format("%1$,.1f", Double.parseDouble(s.get(n).toString()));
            }
            i += 1;

            if((i%2 == 0) && i!=0){
                this.addRow(data);
                i = 0;
                n += 1;
                data = new String[2];
            }
        }
        System.out.println("Prueba");
    }
}
```

Parte 4:

```
import javax.swing.*;
import java.awt.*;

public class TabCalc extends JPanel {

    public void tabFill(String PBM, String Year){
        setLayout(new BorderLayout());
        MatCalc matc = new MatCalc();
        matc.creaTable(PBM, Year);
        JTable table = new JTable(matc);
        JScrollPane scroll = new JScrollPane(table);
        add(scroll,BorderLayout.CENTER);
    }
}
```

La interfaz recibe la primera vez los datos correctamente y ejecuta el código y muestra todo perfecto, pero al momento de borrar la información "en teoría" e ingresar nuevos datos se sigue mostrando el resultado de la consulta anterior.

¿Cómo puedo solucionar esto? ¡Gracias!

En teoría dentro del método del actionListener se deberían tomar los nuevos datos (que creo que lo hace) pero al parecer entonces no llegan a la consulta o algo parecido.

Comment: No tienes que teorizar nada ni suponer nada. Simplemente **ve depurando el código** empezando por donde sospechas que podría estar el fallo. Así encontrarás el problema con suma facilidad. Digo esto no solo para este caso, sino para todos los casos futuros. **Aprender a depurar te va a ahorrar muchas horas a la semana** y eso a la larga se traduce en meses ahorrados y evitar muchos dolores de cabeza.

Comment: Ya lo hice, y pues en el método del actionListener está funcionando pero cuando vacio los campos de texto e ingreso nueva información, simplemente el método del botón no obtiene los datos, y no sé por qué si la primera vez sí. :'c

Comment: Pues depura en esa parte del código entonces. Sí en un punto los datos llegan bien, pasa a depurar en otro punto de tu programa.

Comment: Sí, eso haré, porque el método de actionPerformed debería responder a los eventos en todo momento y no una única vez, ¿cierto?

Comment: Sí, en teoría. Pero tienes que revisar la lógica, incluso el mismo evento podría quedar sin ningún efecto en algunos casos. Por eso tienes que seguirle la pista a tu código depurando punto por punto hasta encontrar qué es lo que le impide funcionar del modo esperado.

Comment: @A.Cedano, gracias!

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Básicamente el problema es que la información nueva, nunca le llega a la tabla, le realicé unos cambios a tu código para que lo haga.

En la clase **GUI**, saque la declaración de **TabCalc** del método **init**, para agregarle un **getter** que me devuelva el panel en cuestión, en la instanciación, le paso un **this**, que voy a usar para llamar al **getter**.

```
public class GUI extends JFrame {

   String pbmGot;
   String yearGot;
   JPanel Principal = new JPanel();
   TabCalc TableR;

   public void init() {

      //Paneles
      JPanel Frame1 = new JPanel();
      JPanel Buttons = new JPanel();

      JLabel jlName = new JLabel( "Nombre" );
      JLabel jlPbm = new JLabel( "PBM" );
      JLabel jlYears = new JLabel( "Año" );

      JTextField jtName = new JTextField( "po" );
      JTextField jtPbm = new JTextField( "78" );
      TableR = new TabCalc( this );
      JComboBox<String> Years = new JComboBox<>();
      Years.addItem( "" );
      Years.addItem( "2019" );
      Years.addItem( "2020" );
      Years.addItem( "2021" );
      Years.addItem( "2022" );
      Years.addItem( "2023" );
      Years.addItem( "2024" );

      jtPbm.addFocusListener( new FocusListener() {
         @Override
         public void focusGained( FocusEvent e ) {
         }
         @Override
         public void focusLost( FocusEvent e ) {
            try {
               Integer PBMd = Integer.valueOf( jtPbm.getText() );
            }
            catch( NumberFormatException nfe ) {
               JOptionPane.showMessageDialog( Frame1, "¡Ingresa un PBM válido!", "Error!", JOptionPane.ERROR_MESSAGE );
               jtPbm.setText( "" );
            }
         }
      });
      JButton buttOK = new JButton( "Enviar" );

      buttOK.addActionListener( new ActionListener() {
         @Override
         public void actionPerformed( ActionEvent e ) {
            pbmGot = jtPbm.getText();
            yearGot = Years.getSelectedItem().toString();
            if( pbmGot.equals( "" ) || yearGot.equals( "" ) ) {
               JOptionPane.showMessageDialog( Principal, "¡Información incompleta!", "Error", JOptionPane.ERROR_MESSAGE );
            }
            else {
               if( Integer.parseInt( pbmGot ) > 100 || Integer.parseInt( pbmGot ) <= 0 ) {
                  JOptionPane.showMessageDialog( Principal, "¡Información errónea!", "Error", JOptionPane.ERROR_MESSAGE );
               }
               else {
                  DBConnect sql = new DBConnect( pbmGot, yearGot );
                  ArrayList<Object> s = sql.ConnectDB();
                  boolean x = (boolean) s.get( 0 );
                  if( x == true ) {
                     JOptionPane.showMessageDialog( Principal, "¡La consulta fue exitosa!", "Aviso", JOptionPane.INFORMATION_MESSAGE );
                     TableR.tabFill( pbmGot, yearGot );
                     Principal.add( TableR, BorderLayout.CENTER );
                     Principal.updateUI();
                  }
               }
            }
         }
      } );

      JButton buttDel = new JButton( "Borrar" );
      buttDel.addActionListener( new ActionListener() {
         @Override
         public void actionPerformed( ActionEvent e ) {
            jtName.setText( "" );
            jtPbm.setText( "" );
            Years.setSelectedItem( "" );
            Principal.remove( TableR );
            Principal.updateUI();
            JOptionPane.showMessageDialog( Principal, "¡Consulta eliminada!", "Aviso", JOptionPane.INFORMATION_MESSAGE );
         }
      } );

      Buttons.setLayout( new GridLayout( 1, 2, 2, 5 ) );
      Buttons.add( buttOK );
      Buttons.add( buttDel );

      Frame1.setLayout( new GridLayout( 4, 2, 5, 2 ) );
      Frame1.add( jlName );
      Frame1.add( jtName );
      Frame1.add( jlPbm );
      Frame1.add( jtPbm );
      Frame1.add( jlYears );
      Frame1.add( Years );

      Principal.setLayout( new BorderLayout() );
      Principal.add( Frame1, BorderLayout.NORTH );
      Principal.add( Buttons, BorderLayout.SOUTH );

      add( Principal );

      setTitle( "Calculadora de matrícula" );
      setSize( 400, 300 );
      setResizable( false );
      setDefaultCloseOperation( WindowConstants.EXIT_ON_CLOSE );
      setLocationRelativeTo( null );
      setVisible( true );
   }

   public TabCalc getTabCalc() {
      return TableR;
   }

   public static void main( String[] args ) {
      GUI gui1 = new GUI();
      gui1.init();
   }
}
```

En la clase **TabCalc**, agregué dos atributos, (un objeto **GUI**, un objeto **JTable**), un constructor con el que inicializo la variable **gui**, y un **getter** para obtener el **JTable**.
El objeto **GUI** lo uso solo para pasarselo al constructor de **MatCalc**.

```
public class TabCalc extends JPanel {
   
   JTable table= new JTable(   );
   GUI gui;

   public TabCalc( GUI g ) {
      gui = g;
   }
   

   public void tabFill( String PBM, String Year ) {
      setLayout( new BorderLayout() );
      MatCalc matc = new MatCalc( gui );
      matc.creaTable( PBM, Year );
      table = new JTable( matc );
      JScrollPane scroll = new JScrollPane( table );
      add( scroll, BorderLayout.CENTER );
   }

   public JTable getTabla() {
      return table;
   }
}
```

Como podrás ver, todo los cambios con para poder obtener en la clase **MatCalc** el **JTable** para cargarle el nuevo modelo de datos.
Se que parece un poco complicado, eso se debe a que tal vez no hayas elegido el camino más práctico para crear tu programa, por ejemplo, la clase **TabCalc** para mi, es innecesaria, pero lo importante ese que funciona.

Finalmente, en la clase **MatCalc**, agregue un constructor (misma finalidad que en **TabCalc**), una linea de código con la que obtengo el **JTable** y una llamada al método **setModel** del mismo, para asignarle la nueva información a mostrar.

```
public class MatCalc extends DefaultTableModel {

   GUI gui;

   public MatCalc( GUI g ) {
      gui = g;
   }

   public void creaTable( String PBM, String Year ) {
      System.out.println( "prubi" );
      ArrayList<String> Labels = new ArrayList<>();
      Labels.add( "Bienestar" );
      Labels.add( "Sistematización" );
      Labels.add( "Póliza o Seguro Estudiantíl" );
      Labels.add( "Matrícula" );
      Labels.add( "Total" );

      this.addColumn( "Concepto" );
      this.addColumn( "Valor Unitario" );

      DBConnect sql = new DBConnect( PBM, Year );
      ArrayList<Object> s = sql.ConnectDB();
      s.remove( 0 );

      Double factor = Double.valueOf( s.get( 0 ).toString() );
      Double salary = Double.valueOf( s.get( 1 ).toString() );

      long mat = Math.round( factor * 0.93 * salary );
      long bt = Math.round( 0.1 * mat );
      long st = Math.round( 0.076 * salary );
      long pz;

      if( Integer.parseInt( Year ) >= 2023 ) {
         pz = Math.round( 25000.0 );
      }
      else {
         pz = Math.round( 24890.0 );
      }
      long total = mat + bt + st + pz;

      s.set( 0, bt );
      s.set( 1, st );
      s.add( 2, pz );
      s.add( 3, mat );
      s.add( 4, total );

      var k = Labels.toArray();
      String[] data = new String[ 2 ];

      int i = 0;
      int n = 0;
      for( int j = 0; j < 10; j++ ) {
         if( i % 2 == 0 ) {
            data[ i ] = k[ n ].toString();
         }
         else {
            data[ i ] = String.format( "%1$,.1f", Double.valueOf( s.get( n ).toString() ) );
         }
         i += 1;

         if( ( i % 2 == 0 ) && i != 0 ) {

            this.addRow( data );
            i = 0;
            n += 1;
            data = new String[ 2 ];
         }
      }
      JTable tabla = gui.getTabCalc().getTabla();
      tabla.setModel( this );
      System.out.println( "Prueba" );
   }
}
```

Comment: entendí la corrección aunque no sé porque la información nueva no llega a la tabla si cuando se ingresan nuevos valores en los campos, el método de creación de la tabla recibe esos parámetros. :'c

Comment: Miguel, la forma de actualizar los datos del `JTable`, es con:  **tabla.setModel( this );**, solo eso le faltaba a tu código.

Comment: ahh, entiendo. ¡Muchas gracias! :')

Comment: Un placer maestro!!

Comment: La primera aproximación no suele ser la mejor, esta no es la excepción, hice cosas innecesarias, para pasarle el objeto **JTable** a **MatCalc**, bastaba con pasarselo desde **TabCalc** como parámetro al método **creaTable**, así: **matc.creaTable( String PBM, String Year, JTable tabla );**.